# Regex to match #hashtag characters in a string

Tags: ios, regex

**My input string:**

*Hello. Is this working? #1#2#3 #testing*

My regex:
`\B[#]\S+\b`

**Output:**
Matches 2:
`#1#2#3`
`#testing`

**What I want:**
Matches 4"
`#1`
`#2`
`#3`
`#testing`

Could someone tell me how to create the expression for this specific match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you just want to match the hashtag followed by word characters. This should be fine, then:

```regex
#\w+
```

If you specifically want to simply avoid whitespace, then just exclude `#` characters in the group with whitespace, like so:

```regex
#[^\s#]+
```

Comment: This does not seem to return the 4 matches that I need. It gives two matches, which is #1 and #testing. Tested in https://regex101.com/

Comment: Seems to correctly retrieve four matches: https://regex101.com/r/jHWrQf/1

Comment: Whoops sorry you are right. `#[^\s#]+` works. Thank you so much! I get it now.

Comment: We have some new requirements. We want to avoid all special characters in the REGEX except for the underscore. How does the expression look? @Exalted Toast

Comment: @Legolas by definition, the word selector `\w` targets alphanumeric and underscore values, so the first expression should work. If you want to explicitly target the same range to easily add/remove characters in maintenance, you can do `#[A-Za-z\d_]+` or, even more explicitly, `#[A-Za-z0-9_]+`